# Cobalt preload API support

Tags: preload, cobalt

With Cobalt RC_9 I tried the following

```
cobalt --url=https://www.youtube.com/tv?launch=preload&additionalDataUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FdialData%2FYouTube
```

but the application does not seem to load in background.

Does Cobalt support YouTube TV preload API yet?

How is the preload API actually supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

The preload API is really just a way to communicate with the HTML application. In Cobalt, this should be done with deep links rather than hash change events.

Cobalt itself doesn't have an explicit preload mechanism, but it can be put in a suspended state where it releases graphics resources.

Comment: Is there a simple way to start Cobalt in background mode?

Comment: Not yet, really. We are planning something for Cobalt 11, but it won't be in Cobalt 9. If your application manager and Starboard Window implementation is sophisticated enough, you could be able to pull it off by launching it normally, but just not displaying it, and then suspend it after 10-15 seconds.